# Navigation help on first login

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, user-experience

I'd like to add a dialog on the front page of my app, when a user first login. The dialog is aimed at helping the user understand where to get started.
Something like what Gmail does when they have introduced a new feature. (see below)

I'm wondering if there is a (React) library to achieve this. Or any guideline. Or if I should simply do it all myself with css.

Unless you guys are unanimous that this is bad UX, and I need to re-arrange the design so I don't need such dialogs.

Thanks for your tips !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When user login to the app for the first time, the user is given a walkthrough of the app. What you are asking is how to implement a walkthrough of your app.

There are multiple libs that provide the functionality to implement a walkthrough to react.
You can use https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour

demo: https://reactour.js.org/